# configure github to work with multiple terminal

Tags: git, bash, github, webstorm

I have installed git and added github as remote repo for my projects, I have been using it for couple of months now either from git bash or "github for window" client(or the power shell that came along with it).

It's all working fine, but now I have just started using webstorm IDE, which has it's own terminal inside IDE, from this terminal I can perform all the git workflow commands, but when I do "git push github master" it ask for my username/password everytime, and this is getting on my nerve(although it does push my changes once I provide my credentials). how can I bypass this ?

While I am not asked for my credentials on git bash or powershell !!!

Comment: Try configuring git bash or powershell as a shell to be used by the built-in terminal (Settings/Tools/Terminal, Shell path)

Comment: I configured "git bash" for now since and it is working as expected, let's see whether it limits my capabilities to do more on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Webstorm IDE function, not a functionality of git. You want Webstorm to store your git password:

> To configure the password policy

```
Open the IDE Settings, then clickPasswords.
On the Passwords page that opens, specify how you want WebStorm to process passwords for Git remote repositories.

Do one fo the following:
    If you do not need WebStorm to save passwords at all, select the Do not remember passwords option.
    To have passwords stored in the memory during a session, select the Remember passwords until closing of the application option.
    To have passwords stored in a passwords database, select the Remember on disk (protected with master password) option and specify the master password for the storage.
```

(see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/handling-passwords-for-git-remote-repositories.html#d328641e233l for more information)

Comment: This didn't worked for me, Even after setting master password default terminal(cmd.exe) in webstorm is still asking for github username/password whenever I am doing "git push....."